# Capitalize the first word after colon space when keypress "enter"

Tags: javascript, string

I am making a small project in which when I press enter once I get normal "R: " and when the press enter again I get bold "**M:** " both followed by space.

The respondent is "R" and the moderator will be asking questions so it needs to be bold. Further, I have tried to introduce voice typing to ease the process, now the problem I am facing is that whenever I voice type, the first letter of the sentence is smallcase, Ideally, the first letter should be in uppercase.

I tried to use regex but it was a failure, what would be the best approach to make the first letter after "R: " or "**M: **" uppercase, using JS?

Following is keypress code that outputs "R: " and "M: " When I press enter,

```js
   

  function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
      var range, selection;
      if (document.createRange) //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
      {
          range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
          range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
          range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
          selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
          selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
          selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
      } else if (document.selection) //IE 8 and lower
      {
          range = document.body.createTextRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
          range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
          range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
          range.select(); //Select the range (make it the visible selection
      }
  }
  var enterPressed = 0;
  window.onkeypress = function (e) {
      var keyCode = (e.keyCode || e.which);

      if (keyCode === 13) {
          if (enterPressed === 0) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var z = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
              z.innerHTML = "<br><b>M:&nbsp; <b>";
              let child = document.getElementById("textbox").appendChild(z);
              setEndOfContenteditable(child)
              enterPressed++;
          } else if (enterPressed === 1) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var z = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
              z.innerHTML = "<br>R:&nbsp;";
              let child = document.getElementById("textbox").appendChild(z);
              setEndOfContenteditable(child)
              enterPressed++;
              enterPressed = 0;

          }
      } else if (keyCode === 92) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var z = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
          z.innerHTML = "<br>R:&nbsp;";
          let child = document.getElementById("textbox").appendChild(z);
          setEndOfContenteditable(child)
          enterPressed = 0;

      }
  };
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="textbox"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the setEndOfContenteditable

Comment: So sorry, let me make the correction

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to capitalize the first letter of something would be like so:

```
let text = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
text = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1)

// text => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
```

To do the above, you must format your HTML in way that would allow you to target the text after R: and M:

for example:

```
R: <span class="body">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

```
const body = document.querySelector('.body')
const text = body.innerText
body.innerText = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1)
```